# jqgrid and datepicker control giving error for new records

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid, jquery-ui-datepicker

i binded by jqgrid with json returned from ajax.  json has date in following format

```
11/1/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

in the colmodel i have specified the following

```
{ name: 'datecol', index: 'SignDate', width: '200', jsonmap: 'cell.SignDate', editable: true, sorttype: 'date',
                    editable: true, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {
                        srcformat: 'm-d-Y H:i:s',
                        newformat: 'Y-M-d'
                    },
editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit },
initDateEdit = function(elem) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(elem).datepicker({
                        formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {
                            srcformat: 'm-d-Y H:i:s',
                            newformat: 'yy-M-d'
                        }
                        autoSize: true,
                        showOn: 'button', // it dosn't work in searching dialog
                        changeYear: true,
                        changeMonth: true,
                        showButtonPanel: true,
                        showWeek: true
                    });
                    //$(elem).focus();
                },100);
            }
```

This displays the date correctly in the grid as

```
2013-Nov-01
```

but when i hit addnew record, the popup comes and when i select the date and hit submit, in the grid, the new record is showing

```
NaN-undefined-NaN
```

in the date column.  what is wrong here?

when I use the same code as given in this link
http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditing.htm

edit works fine, but when i add new row, the date comes as NaN-undefined-NaN

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the reason of the problem which you described is wrong parameters of jQuery UI Datepicker which you use. You use `formatter` and `formatoptions` parameters of `datepicker` which not exists. Instead of that you should use [dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) option which format described [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate).

**UPDATED**: The main reason of the problem which you describe is wrong date format which you use. It's important to understand that `srcformat` and `newformat` of `formatoptions` should have [PHP date format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), but jQuery UI Datepicker supports another format which described [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate) for example. The input data `11/1/2013 12:00:00 AM` contains both date and time. On the other side jQuery UI Datepicker support date only. Because you use `newformat: 'yy-M-d'` then I suppose that you want just ignore the time part of the date. In the case I would suggest you to use

```
formatter: 'date',
formatoptions: {
    srcformat: 'm/d/Y',
    newformat: 'Y-m-d'
}
```

instead of

```
formatter: 'date',
formatoptions: {
    srcformat: 'm-d-Y H:i:s',
    newformat: 'Y-m-d'
}
```

which you use currently. Next problem is the `dateFormat` option of jQuery UI Datepicker. You have to use format which corresponds `srcformat`, but which uses correct format (described [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate)). In case of `srcformat: 'm/d/Y'` you should use `dateFormat: 'm/d/yy'` instead of `dateFormat: 'yy-m-dd'` which you use in your [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/needhelp18/Bnqkv/13/).

[The modified demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bnqkv/16/) works now correctly.

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  i have changed the code as below.  My col model is
 editable: true, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {
                            srcformat: 'm/d/Y H:i:s',
                            newformat:'d-M-Y'
                        },
                        datefmt: 'd-M-Y',
                            editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit },
                            searchoptions: { dataInit: initDateSearch }
                        }  and in initDateEdit function i have removed the formatter options and given  dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' as in your sample.  but still i get the error.

Comment: the error comes only when i add a new report and select a date and hit submit.  in the add dialog, it shows the correct date, but when i submit, it shows this error in the jqgrid.

Comment: somebody please help.  i found this is something related to the jquery includes.  is this the correct order of files that i need to include?  
jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css
ui.jqgrid.css
jquery-1.9.1.min.js
jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js
grid.locale-en.js
jquery.jqGrid.js
jquery.fmatter.js
am i missing any file?  plz help.

Comment: @user1447718: Do you have a demo which reproduce the problem? Please use `grid.locale-en.js` and `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` in the demo. It's not important to have any backend. One can use Fiddler, Firebug or any other tool to catch HTTP traffic and see which data (correct date or `NaN-undefined-NaN` are sent). One can use alternatively `serializeEditData` to trace the data posted to the server. My problem is just I can't reproduce the problem which you described.

Comment: Thanks for the response Oleg.  Am not sure how to put my code in fiddler, but will find out.  i replaced the libraries with the libraries that you have used, it works fine.  so in your sample, if you replace the libraries with latest version of jquery, jqueryui and jqgrid, then you will be able to see the problem, i believe.  if you don't, then that will be the solution to my problem.

Comment: @user1447718: I replaced all libraries to the last versions. [The resulting demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditing_.htm) seems to work without any problem which I can see. Could you describe the exact test case in the demo which produce the error date `NaN-undefined-NaN`?

Comment: Thanks Oleg.  am not able to reproduce the error now.  i believe it has got to do something with the date format that i want to show.  the date format that i want is 2013-08-27.  but even then i don't get the NaN issue now.  not sure why.  i just used the same libraries that i used before, but i now pulled the files from jqgrid 4.5.2.  maybe some version issue.  but now am facing a different issue.  instead of NaN, it is showing me a random #.  you can find the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/needhelp18/Bnqkv/13/). I fidler, even if i don't use srcFormat, am able to see date in yy-m-dd format.

Comment: but in my code, when i don't add srcFormat, jqgrid does not convert the data properly.only change from mycode to fiddler is the jquery version.  try adding a new row and you will see random #.  if you remove srcFormat, then it will work fine. but in my code if i remove srcformat, the initial date display is not fine.In my code if i don't add srcFormat 2013-11-01 is shown as 2016-07-05. but adding new row works fine.  the opposite ishappening in fiddler.  if i remove srcFormat, both load and new row works fine.

Comment: also, the code, both urs and mine are not working in IE8.  what can i do to makeit work in IE8? thanks.

Comment: @user1447718: You are welcome! I modified [your demo](http://jsfiddle.net/needhelp18/Bnqkv/13/) to [the following](http://jsfiddle.net/Bnqkv/16/) which work correctly. I described the modifications in **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Oleg.  this answers the problem.  also i see that the ur demo is not working in IE8.  i throws a client side error in some jquery library.  how can we fix that?

Comment: @user1447718: You are welcome! I don't have IE8. My demo works if I specify IE8 browser mode in Developer Tools of IE10 which I have. If you can reproduce an error you should start script debugging of Developer Tools of IE8 (press F12 to start) during executing of [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bnqkv/16/embedded/result/). In case of error you can look in "Call Stack" and find the place in `jQuery.jqGrid.src.js` where the error take place. You can see values of all variables. It should provide enough information to localize the problem.